# WCF Interface as parameter

Tags: wcf

I am using interface as input parameter in OperationContract. But when i generate proxy class at client side. I am not able to access the members of interface or class implemeting the ITransaction interface. I am only geeting is object

1. Service Interface

   ```
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IServiceInterface
   {
   [OperationContract]
   string SyncDatabase(ITransaction TransactionObject);
   }
   ```
2. Service class

   ```
   class SyncService:IServiceInterface
   {

       public string SyncDatabase(ITransaction TransactionObject)
       {
       return "Hello There!!";    
       }
   }
   ```
3. Interface

   ```
   public interface ITransaction
   {
       ExpenseData ExpData { get; set; }
       void Add(ITransaction transactionObject);
   }
   ```
4. Data Contract

   ```
   [DataContract]
   public class Transaction:ITransaction
   {
       [DataMember]
       public ExpenseData ExpData
       {
           get;
           set;
       }

       public void Add(ITransaction transactionObject)
       {

       }

    }
   ```

In above case should i also copy the iTransaction class and interface on client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your interface the `[DataContract]` and use the `[KnownType]` attribute to tell WCF what the known implementations of that interface are.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Transaction))]
public interface ITransaction
{
    [DataMember]
    ExpenseData ExpData { get; set; }
    void Add(ITransaction transactionObject);
}
```

Comment: When i follow your approach everything is fine. But my second part of question still remains answered. When I create proxy of the service I don't get the Transaction class on client. what should I do get this class on client as well.

Comment: Actually the `[KnownType(typeof(Transaction))]` is supposed to tell WCF to include that type in the WSDL, so I'm not sure why that wouldn't work for you.  Are you sure you regenerated the client after making the change?

Comment: From the msdn:

`[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class|AttributeTargets.Struct, Inherited=true, AllowMultiple=true)] 
public sealed class KnownTypeAttribute : Attribute`

... meaning the attribute cannot be applied on an interface...
This is the same for DataContractAttribute

Answer (score 6):

You actually need to make your ServiceContract aware of the implementation of the interface you pass as a parameter, so WCF will include it in the WSDL.

This should work:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Transaction))]
public interface IServiceInterface
{
     [OperationContract]
     string SyncDatabase(ITransaction TransactionObject);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `[KnownType(typeof(testClass))]`.

Refer these links:

- [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx)
- [www.codeproject.com/Tips/108807/Implementing-KnownType-Attribute](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/108807/Implementing-KnownType-Attribute)

Comment: The second link is great. For short, use a class instead of interface as the parameter type.